# Disable Firefox warnings about password fields in a non-HTTPS website

Tags: firefox, popups

Starting from Firefox 51 it shows a warning below a password field in a form when you're in a non-HTTPS website.

How can we disable this nasty popup?

Comment: Keep in mind that getting a HTTPS supported website is not that hard anymore, and firefox and chrome are doing this to try and push webdevelopers to secure their websites. Hackers on the other hand won't be able to do this, so in essence by changing this, you are removing a warning when you are redirected to a fake login page.

Comment: Yes I know. On my production sites I use Ssl certs from Comodo, or Let's Encrypt in the hosting services that allow it. But when you're testing a project in localhost you cannot use a free SSL cert until you buy or use an external domain hacking the hosts file. As the advisor of the config:about says you should know what you're doing before changing something there.

Comment: My comment was not just directed to you, but to every visitor here on SuperUser. ;) It never hurts to tell people that the answer provided here is to be used at their own risk, and is better to avoid.

Comment: I understand. I added a note on the top of my answer ;-)

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/disable-insecure-password-warning-firefox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Remember you're doing it *at your own risk* of sending password to a
>   website in a non-secure way.
>
> I needed this because I work as programmer and usually I'm testing
>   websites on my local computer.

1. Type `about:config` in the URL bar.
2. Accept the warning about you will enter in a danger zone.
3. Search `security.insecure_field_warning` with the text-field.
4. Change the value of the option `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` to `false`, double-clicking on it.